# ubuntu cannot install gparted

Tags: 14.04, gparted

I'm trying to run `gparted` on fresh install of `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`.

In unity search when I write `gparted` it responds with 'No results found'.

In terminal I write `sudo apt-get install gparted` and it responds its already installed, but when I write `gparted` it tells me it's not installed, so I'm puzzled with this problem.

Comment: can you launch it from terminal ? Try to type `gparted` in terminal. Or Press Alt F2 . Also check `which gparted` output to find out where the command may be located

Comment: In terminal the commad `gparted` outputs its not yet installed, `which gparted` outputs nothing

Comment: very interesting . . .  what if you do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted` ?

Comment: This output that gparted is already installed... i described it all in my question

Comment: Yes, I see that. But have you tried that with updating first ?

Comment: Yep i run your line of code with update and the result were unfortunately the same.

Comment: Have you tried with **reinstall** i.e. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gparted`?

Comment: Please add the output of `dpkg -L gparted` and `locate gparted`.

Comment: Yes! `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gparted` that worked but still i dont understand where was the problem, please write this in an answer so i can accept it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the package management system (`dpkg` and/or `apt`) thinks that a package is installed and up-to-date, however some essential component has been manually removed. In that case, reinstalling the package usually fixes things - in this case

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gparted
```

From `man apt-get`:

```
   --reinstall
       Re-install packages that are already installed and at the newest
       version. Configuration Item: APT::Get::ReInstall.
```